# recognize formatted numbers using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

```
1      #valid
1,5    #valid
1,5,   #invalid
,1,5   #invalid
1,,5   #invalid
       #'nothing' is also invalid
```

The number of numbers separated by commas can be arbitrary.

I'm trying to use regex to do this. This is what I have tried so far, but none of it worked:

```
"1,2,," =~ /^[[\d]+[\,]?]+$/      #returned 0
"1,2,," =~ /^[\d\,]+$/            #returned 0
"1,2,," =~ /^[[\d]+[\,]{,1}]+$/   #returned 0
"1,2,," =~ /^[[\d]+\,]+$/         #returned 0
```

Obviously, I needed the expression to recognize that `1,2,,` is invalid, but they all returned `0` :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patternsare not really working because:

- `^[[\d]+[\,]?]+$` - matches a line that contains one or more digit, `+`, `,`, `?` chars (and matches all the strings above but the last empty one)
- `^[\d\,]+$`  - matches a line that consists of 1+ digits or `,` symbols
- `^[[\d]+[\,]{,1}]+$` -  matches a line that contains one or more digit, `+`, `,`, `{` and `}` chars
- `^[[\d]+\,]+$` -  matches a line that contains one or more digit, `+`, and `,` chars.

Basically, the issue is that you try to rely on a *character class*, while you need a *grouping* construct, `(...)`.

Comma-separated whole numbers can be validated with

```
/\A\d+(?:,\d+)*\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/c5uI5ZhnRm).

**Details**:

- `\A`  - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: what is the difference between `[]` and `()`?

Comment: `[abc]` finds 1 character, either `a`,`b` or `c`. `(abc|def)`  will find either a literal char sequence `abc` or `def`. `[...]` are character classes/bracket expressions and `(...)` are grouping constructs. `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group (does not store the part of the match in a separate memory buffer).

Comment: what is `:` in the context of `?:,`? I tried using it like this: `{1}:,` but it didnt work.

Comment: Also note that the character class inside a character class makes a union. Thus, `[[\d][^\w]]+` will match 1+ chars that are either digits or chars other than word chars. As for `(?:...)`, I already noted above, that it is a [**non-capturing group**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon).